# Can a 208-230/460 blower motor be wired for 220 plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, electric-motor, voltage

This is my motor

[image]

I have this blower fan squirrel cage thing and is belt driven by this 3 phase motor and I just want to know if it is possible to wire to plug in my shop wall outlet? If so I probably won’t do it myself but will at least keep until I can find someone to do it.

[image]

Comment: That's a three-phase motor. Yes, it can run on 220V single-phase but you need a capacitor for it. Let an electrician handle that.

Comment: @Janka it'll take a bit more than a capacitor.  Capacitors have 2 wires.   This black box would need at least 3.

Comment: ...Unless (vanishingly small odds but not unthinkable, depending where the shop is) there's 3-phase power available.

Comment: I've proposed some appropriate tags, and an edit to the question to highlight your actual question.  If you don't like it, you might want to consider similar edits.  (Sorry for your lost by the way).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica No. the motor has three wires the 240V plug has two wires, so only 1 wire is missing. the black box needs only 1 wire in and one wire out. using capacitors to run 3 phase motors on single phase since is a long established practice.

Answer (score 2):

### $600 solution

You can fit a phase converter, which will take single-phase 240V power and synthesize 240V 3-phase delta (by creating the phantom third phase electronically).

### $400 solution

You can replace the entire motor with any bog-standard 240V single-phase 5 horsepower motor that is 3450 RPM.

Comment: How big of a shop do you have that would need a 5hp blower?  I have a 24" whole house fan that moves 2800 cfm for a 1000 ft^2 house, another 30" that moves 7500 cfm for a 3000 ft^2 house, both with 1/3 hp motors, and a 3/4 hp dust collector that'll literally suck golf balls through 60ft+ of 4" hose.  Each of these cost $250 or less.  It would probably be more economical and more maintainable to use something designed for closer to your application.

Comment: @EricSimpson Maybe the motor is oversized for the job.

Comment: Here is a picture of the monstrosity that a friend gave to my brother and I and not so much that we need it but something to have. Didn’t really want to junk it and figured it must have some value but not something we want to put more than 50 to a 100 dollars in. Just did not know what it would take and came across the site and seemed like the post’s were friendly and knowledgeable so I thought I would see what y’all thought.  I do appreciate all the responses.  Sorry I thought I had a picture in there. Added picture to original post.

Comment: Note that if you ebay the current motor, replacing it with a single phase may have a net cost much less than 400.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions and helping with my post this is only the second time I ever really posted in a forum and please Reinstate Monica!!!!

Comment: @NotsureTelford Thanks.  Yes, CraigsList could be your friend here.